# How can I download songs from a spotify playlist to my desired folder all Tuesdays at 00:00 with spotdl?

Tags: cron, spotify

How can I download songs from a spotify playlist to my desired folder all Tuesdays at 00:00  with spotdl?

Comment: create a cron job and put a spotdl command in it?